Upload a file with ftp-simple in VS Code without going through selecting path manually in Command Palette
When executing

Save - Upload to FTP Server command VS Code starts asking where to save.


Can it "auto-select" the same folder on FTP Server as it is locally?
The problem is that when a folder is not the top one a the target file is not the top one it takes a lot of time to find them, aim, and click.
